# after call end, relaunch the previous app in iphone

Tags: iphone, call

I can make a call from my app by use this APIs.
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:XXXXXX"]];`

I would like to return to my app where I left after the users ends the call. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

UIWebView *callingWebview;

[callingWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:]];

Answer (score 1):

no it's not possible

Comment: ok thx but there is a application where it is happening i m giving you reference for that apps
http://www.codegoo.com/page/baby-monitor

here it is going on???

Comment: Yeah it is possible.Through this code..
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt:XXXXXX"]];